# How can I force a nested div to fit exactly in the parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a webpage layout where I have a few paragraphs followed by a list underneath.

I want the page to be the height of the viewport, and `.lower` to scroll if `.lower` is too tall to fit on screen.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lower {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

However, with this CSS, my `.lower` is too tall and the last few items aren't visible. I think I want the height of `.lower` to be (in pseudocode) `100vh - height(.upper)`.

Can I achieve this layout using CSS?

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.lower {
  max-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="upper">
    <p>hello world
    </p>
    <p>hello world again
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="lower">
    <ul>
      <li>hello world 1</li>
      <li>hello world 2</li>
      <li>hello world 3</li>
      <li>hello world 4</li>
      <li>hello world 5</li>
      <li>hello world 6</li>
      <li>hello world 7</li>
      <li>hello world 8</li>
      <li>hello world 9</li>
      <li>hello world 10</li>
      <li>hello world 11</li>
      <li>hello world 12</li>
      <li>hello world 13</li>
      <li>hello world 14</li>
      <li>hello world 15</li>
      <li>hello world 16</li>
      <li>hello world 17</li>
      <li>hello world 18</li>
      <li>hello world 19</li>
      <li>hello world 20</li>
      <li>hello world 21</li>
      <li>hello world 22</li>
      <li>hello world 23</li>
      <li>hello world 24</li>
      <li>hello world 25</li>
      <li>hello world 26</li>
      <li>hello world 27</li>
      <li>hello world 28</li>
      <li>hello world 29</li>
      <li>hello world 30</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is the content in `.upper` dynamic or static?  That will determine the solution, and whether you need JavaScript or not.

Comment: It's static, but I'd prefer a solution that handles dynamic content to save me updating CSS every time I change the content of `.upper`.

Answer (score 2):

If using a fixed (known) height for the upper element is acceptable then you could use `calc()` :

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYgvab?editors=110)

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.upper p {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.lower {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px dotted red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've avoided using `vh` for `.lower` directly because of issues when being used inside CSS calc().

Comment: Thanks. I could live with making `.upper` a fixed size, but is it possible without hard-coding a size?

Comment: Flexbox has a bit less browser support but Pangloss' solution looks good that way (just needs an additional removal of the default margin on `body` to have the exact effect). Not sure I could think of another approach without resorting to relative units for it all or JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It can be quite easy to do it with `flexbox`. Note, added a container div.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}
.lower {
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7exw7j9/1/)

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}
.lower {
    flex: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="upper">
        <p>hello world</p>
        <p>hello again</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lower">
        <ul>
            <li>hello world 1</li>
            <li>hello world 2</li>
            <li>hello world 3</li>
            <li>hello world 4</li>
            <li>hello world 5</li>
            <li>hello world 6</li>
            <li>hello world 7</li>
            <li>hello world 8</li>
            <li>hello world 9</li>
            <li>hello world 10</li>
            <li>hello world 11</li>
            <li>hello world 12</li>
            <li>hello world 13</li>
            <li>hello world 14</li>
            <li>hello world 15</li>
            <li>hello world 16</li>
            <li>hello world 17</li>
            <li>hello world 18</li>
            <li>hello world 19</li>
            <li>hello world 20</li>
            <li>hello world 21</li>
            <li>hello world 22</li>
            <li>hello world 23</li>
            <li>hello world 24</li>
            <li>hello world 25</li>
            <li>hello world 26</li>
            <li>hello world 27</li>
            <li>hello world 28</li>
            <li>hello world 29</li>
            <li>hello world 30</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
html, body {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.lower{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Now, this `.lower` element fit the size of the viewport. But i'm not sure if is that what you want. Let meknow if i got you wrong.

Comment: There needs to be a scrollbar on `.lower` so it fits in the space not taken by `.upper`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few assumptions: your browser is on a small screen media and the scroll isn't visible, which is why you can't view the last few items .lower section.  Have you tried changing hidden to auto of the overflow in .body, and changing scroll to visible in .lower (as to not rely on the scroll-bar function)?

Comment: No, the reason the items aren't visible is that the div is too big for the viewport. See my snippet.